# Joining 2 tables in which the common row has different data formats

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in my database, one is `tablea`, and the other is `tableb`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TABLEA
```

Results in:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║           ip                          mac           ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║         1.10.0.0.97               00 14 2A 2F 72 FE ║
║        1.10.0.0.98                08 CC 68 71 A1 C0 ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝



SELECT * 
FROM   TABLEB
```

Results in:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════════╗
║     mac                          port ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════════╣
║     0:14:2a:2f:72:fe               24 ║
║     8:cc:68:71:a1:c0                7 ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I now want to create a third table , which joins tablea and table c and has 3 columns displaying ip,mac and port. the table has already been created and this is what i have in mind;

```
INSERT INTO TABLEC 
SELECT A.IP, 
       A.MAC, 
       B.PORT 
FROM   TABLEA A, 
       TABLEB B 
WHERE  A.MAC = REPLACE('REPLACE('B.MAC',':',' ')','0','00')
```

The query gives me an error

```
ERROR 1064(42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near 'b.mac',':',' ')','0','00')
```

I have checked the manual and i could not identify where my error is . And also my replace function can be able to convert  0:14:2a:2f:72:fe   to 00 14 2A 2F 72 FE but it will not work if tried for 8:cc:68:71:a1:c0. I would really appreciate any help i can get in creating this 3rd table

Comment: remove the quotes from `'b.mac'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove `'` before `replace` and after `)` and the quotes around `b.mac`. 
Also you can't replace `0` with `00` because for `c0` it will return `c00` you should use **[LPAD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)** instead.

```
INSERT INTO TABLEC 
SELECT A.IP, 
       A.MAC, 
       B.PORT 
FROM   TABLEA A, 
       TABLEB B 
WHERE  A.MAC = UPPER(LPAD(REPLACE(B.MAC, ':', ' '), 17, '0'))
```

[**SQL Fiddle DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc0944/12/0)

Comment: it still gives an error                                           #check your manual for the right syntax to use near ' '#

Comment: @juergend Thanks! Ive removed it

Comment: but then with that function, a.mac will not be able to be compared to b.mac since only the colons are replaced, also, i forgot to mention that the datatypes are varchar in all cases

Comment: @sosytee Try to add LPAD as above

Comment: i still get a value NULL in my port table and i think i understand why, since mac is varchar, in mysql it would be wrong to compare it as a number i.e  a.mac=upper(LPAD(replace(b.mac,':',' '),17,'0')) should be like  a.mac='upper(LPAD(replace(b.mac,':',' '),17,'0'))'. But then when i make that modification, i get an error, i really appreciate the help thanks

Comment: thank you, i did see the demo, but it is not working on my server, maybe because of version

Comment: @sosytee In your server do you see data from `tableA` ?

Comment: @sosytee can you include example from your case?

Answer (score 2):

you should lpad (with 0) tableb.mac before doing your replace.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO tablec
SELECT a.ip, a.mac, b.port
FROM tablea a 
LEFT JOIN tableb b 
ON a.mac = upper(LPAD(replace(b.mac,':',' '),17,'0'))
```

[parado's replace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18735032/1579182) has more sense than the one i wrote -

Comment: i get a result but there is null in all rows of Port , i wonder if the matching is still not correct

Comment: edited... parado's solution is the same, but i'd recommend you to use "join"